# How to Make it so that the User ends this program?

Tags: java, loops, simulator

```
// ************************************************************
// ELEVATOR.java
//
// ELEVAOTR SIMULATION
// PROBLEM: NEED TO FIND A WAY TO AMKE IT SO THAT THE PROGRAM KEEPS RNNING AFTER USER INPUTS 
// THIER FIRST DESIRED FLOOR.
// ************************************************************
import java.util.*;


public class Elevator_Simulation {

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Person User = new Person();
        Floor floors = new Floor();
        floors.moveElevator(User.getDesiredFloor()); 

    }
}

class Elevator { //NEEDS SETTER & GETTER METHODS 
    private int mass=0;
    private int capcity=0; 
    private String name="";
    private String color="";
}

class Floor { 


    ArrayList<Object> floorLevel = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Elevator Lift = new Elevator();
    Person Man = new Person();

    Floor() { //Floors 0-9
        floorLevel.add(Lift); //0
        floorLevel.add(null); //1
        floorLevel.add(null); //2
        floorLevel.add(null); //3
        floorLevel.add(null); //4
        floorLevel.add(null); //5
        floorLevel.add(null); //6
        floorLevel.add(null); //7
        floorLevel.add(null); //8
        floorLevel.add(null); //9
        }
        System.out.println("Elevator is at Floor: " + floorLevel.indexOf(Lift)  );


    public void moveElevator (int chosenFloor) {

        if (chosenFloor > 9) {
            System.out.println("Woooooah Buddy! You can only choose 0-9!");
            return;
        }
        if (chosenFloor == floorLevel.indexOf(Lift)) {
            System.out.println("Bro you're already on that floor...");
        }

            while (floorLevel.indexOf(Lift)>chosenFloor) {
                Collections.swap(floorLevel, floorLevel.indexOf(Lift), ( floorLevel.indexOf(Lift)-1 ) );
                System.out.println(floorLevel.indexOf(Lift) );
            }
            while (floorLevel.indexOf(Lift)<chosenFloor) {
                Collections.swap(floorLevel, floorLevel.indexOf(Lift), ( floorLevel.indexOf(Lift)+1 ) );
                System.out.println(floorLevel.indexOf(Lift) );
            }   

    }
}

class Person { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public int getDesiredFloor() {
        int desiredFloor = scan.nextInt();
        return desiredFloor;
    }
}
```

Above is an Elevator Simulator Code (before I attempt to make one with a GUI) and my only problem, aside from the obvious beginner flaws, is that I'm having trouble of finding a way to make it so that the program doesn't just end once the user inputs one floor. I at least want the program to run until the user ends it with a command. I'm thinking of using a while loop somewhere but where? Please help and point out anything I should improve in this code.

Comment: BTW consider changing `if (chosenFloor > 9) ` to `if (chosenFloor > 9 || chosenFloor < 0) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `while` loop around the line

```
floors.moveElevator(User.getDesiredFloor());
```

Just add an input check for a value that represents exiting.

Comment: THANKS! that makes sense, though i have to put an input twice in the command line for it to go, and ideas why?

Comment: @JevonÇøö No, probably because the code you posted is not the same as the one you're running. If you add `while(true)` before the line I mentioned it works fine.